# Can I integrate a native android java application in flutter project?

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin

I have a native android java simple game applications. Now I want to build a flutter project that will have all those native game apps. Can I integrate them in flutter project?

I tried copying the native project folder in android directory of the flutter project but could not figure out how to integrate properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by using platform channels, but you have to do some work.
Here is for your reference: https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: its not relevant. Its saying about calling platform specific code, I am talking about integrating a complete native app and navigating to it.